# pdf.js memory leak when generating thumbnails

Tags: javascript, node.js, pdf, pdf.js, nw.js

I'm in the process of creating an nw.js application that needs to show loads of PDF's. The PDF's are initially downloaded the first time you start the application. In the initialization phase I also need to create a thumbnail for each PDF to be shown in lists.

The thumbnail generation itself doesn't seem to be an issue when we had a few PDF's. It works by creating a canvas element and having PDF.js draw the first page, and then save the canvas to a PNG.

The issue is that PDF.js doesn't seem to unload the PDF between runs. Loading 20 1MB PDF files usually leads to nw.js using around 500MB RAM. Now we would have 100+, maybe even thousands of PDFs, so we need to figure out how to free the RAM between each thumbnail, since at around 80 or so PDFs, nw.js already uses 2GB of RAM and freezes my laptop as it runs out of memory.

I've made a simple test that shows this issue:

```
var fs = require("fs");
var Q = require("q");
var glob = require("glob");

var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

PDFJS.workerSrc = "pdf.worker.js";

function pdf(pdfFile) {
    return new Q.Promise(function (fulfill, reject) {
        PDFJS.getDocument(pdfFile).then(function (pdf) {

            pdf.getPage(1).then(function (page) {
                var viewport = page.getViewport(0.5);

                canvas.height = viewport.height;
                canvas.width = viewport.width;

                var renderContext = {
                    canvasContext: ctx,
                    viewport: viewport
                };

                page.render(renderContext).then(function () {
                    //set to draw behind current content
                    ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "destination-over";

                    //set background color
                    ctx.fillStyle = "#ffffff";

                    //draw background / rect on entire canvas
                    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
                    var img = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
                    img = img.replace(/^data:image\/png;base64,/, "");
                    fs.writeFile(pdfFile + ".png", img, 'base64', function (err) {
                        console.log("Done thumbnail for: " + pdfFile);
                        fulfill();
                    });
                });
            });
        });
    });
}

glob("pdf/*.pdf", function (err, files) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
    } else {
        function generate(file) {
            console.log("Generating thumb for: " + file);
            pdf(file).then(function() {
                if(files.length > 0) next();
            });
        }
        function next() {
            var file = files.pop();
            generate(file);
        }

        next();
    }
});
```

I've never done anything like this before. I've tried to reuse the same canvas for all thumbs but that didn't seem to change a thing.

I've tried to do a heap snapshot in developer tools to see what takes up all the RAM, but guess what? It seems to trigger a garbage collection before doing the snapshot, so nw.js goes from 500MB to around 100MB before doing the snapshot. This makes me believe that the objects are actually marked for deletion but that the GC never has the chance to run before the computer runs out of RAM. Loading 20 files and then just wait doesn't trigger a GC though, and neither does running out of RAM.

I've tried to check the API and documentation of PDF.js, but I could not find anything mentioning how to unload a PDF before loading the next one.

Any ideas on how I should proceed? An idea I had was to call some external tool or make a c/c++ lib that I would call using node-ffi, but I'd have to use PDF.js to show the PDF's at a later state anyway and I'd imagine I would just run into the same issue again.

Comment: There are cleanup() and destroy() functions https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/blob/master/src/display/api.js#L557

Comment: Ohhh, that might explain why I couldn't find anything, in my tired state I was searching for things like dispose and unload. I'll check this out

Comment: I've tried the same code with cleanup() and destroy() being called after the thumb is written to disk, and now nw stays within 200 - 450mb while generating ~800 thumbs for the same pdf, so it seems to be working alright. If you post this as an answer then I can mark it as the correct solution.